# Xamarin parsing Html

Tags: c#, xamarin, html-agility-pack

I need parse HTML,  but I have problems.

I need get from this html code `imgSRC` and `text`

```
<div class="div1Class">
    <div id="div1ID">
        <div class="div3Class">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="imgSRC"/>
                    <div>
                        <h3 class="subject">text</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tryed `HtmlAgilityPack` and their `DocumentNode`, but I don´t know how it works.

Thank in advance.

Comment: It's a full presentation of your HTML? Maybe image has some other attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your html, described above, you can use this code:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
//your html stream
document.Load(stream);
var container = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "div3Class");
if (container != null)
{
    var image = container.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes.Contains("src"));
    if (image != null)
    {
        var imageSrcValue = image.Attributes["src"].Value;
    }

    var subjectItem = container.Descendants("h3").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes.Contains("class") && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "subject");
    if (subjectItem != null)
    {
        var subjectItemValue = subjectItem.InnerText;
    }
}
```